# Micronaut JSON serialization - use getters instead of fields

Tags: java, jackson, micronaut

When using Spring MVC, by default, whenever your @RestControllers return an object, it will be serialized into a JSON based on its getters, instead of its fields.

Is there any way I can configure Micronaut to behave like this as well? Example:

```
public class User {

  private String email;
  private String password;

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

}

@Controller
public class UserController {

  public User getUser() {
    ...
  }

}
```

So this should return:

```
{
  "email": "email@addres.com"
}
```

instead of this:

```
{
  "email": "email@addres.com",
  "password": "pass"
}
```

I'm aware of Jackson's annotations, however, I'm just trying to understand if it's possible to configure Micronaut to behave like this.

Thanks.

Comment: Does `micronaut` use reflection? [How Does it Work](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#how)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I don't think it's related to the question, as this is explaining that Bean definitions do not rely on reflection. I have clearly framed my question in the wrong way, though: actually, what I'm trying to achieve is to configure jackson to use getters instead of fields. I have just updated the question.

Comment: Ok, but your example produces the exact json as you describe... you only miss the `@Get` on your endpoint

Comment: Not really. In the example I gave, the password is being serialized as well.

Comment: Realy? Without a getter, it should not... And it does not if I try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work as expected, it should not be displaying the password. No fields are displayed if there is **no** getter (password).

Starting with a project without any features: [micronaut launch](https://micronaut.io/launch/)

Then

```
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Micronaut.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

class User {
    String email;
    String password;

    public User(String email,String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}

@Controller
class UserController {

    @Get
    public User getUser() {
        return new User("email@micronaut.io","secret");
    }

}
```

`http://localhost:8080` results in:

```
{
"email": "email@address.com"
}
```

Comment: Well, not sure what happened either. I have just regenerated the project using the launch and now it's working as expected. Thanks for your time.